# How to add a specific block on the sidebar for the page "terms and conditions"?

Tags: if-statement, bigcommerce

I know it is on the page.html template but what could be the identifier for that page? There is a possible code like {{ if page "==" 'slug'}} that will identify that part will be added on the page? adding a custom template is another option but it is a bit tricky for me. Any solution for this? This is for Stencil BigCommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom template, you can use the `{{#if}}` block helper like this to render a sidebar only on a certain page:

```
{{#if page.title '===' 'Terms and Conditions'}}
<html for your sidebar>
{{/if}}
```

Here's a link to the documentation on the `{{page}}` object in Stencil, with all of the properties you can access: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/page-content-object

Comment: I think that there should be something like that conditional statement. Thanks for the answer. I will test it first.

Comment: is the title referring to the Page Name or the Page Title(Advanced Options)?